Is the parse function in vue-currency-input deprecated?
I am working with some older code that uses vue-currency-input and relies heavily on the parse() function from vue-currency-input. However, I get an error for this function:
TypeError: this.$parseCurrency is not a function
Is this function deprecated? What does / did it do and how can i replace it in my code?
Note that I have imported vue-currency-input and also installed it
import {useCurrencyInput} from "vue-currency-input";

Not sure what I should try, I researched a lot and I found other people with the same problem but no solution that worked for me. Importing parse like this did not work:
import {parse} from "vue-currency-input";


The function was deprecated in v3.0.0

BREAKING CHANGES
parse is no longer needed, since numberValue is exposed by useCurrencyInput.

